# Error in adding dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, applozic

I am trying to add

```
 compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:3.38'
```

under dependencies in build.gradle but it is giving the following error
[image: Here is the whole logcat]

I have added

```
include 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:3.38'
```

in settings.gradle.

Please help, I am new to these things.
The link from which I am trying to implement my project is [here](https://www.applozic.com/developers.html#android-sdk-overview)
Here is build.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
packagingOptions{

    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'


}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.urjapawar.bevyphase1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:3.38'

}
```

and here is build.gradle(module:project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

here is the log after cleaning project

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:3.38.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/applozic/communication/uiwidget/mobicomkitui/3.38/mobicomkitui-3.38.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/applozic/communication/uiwidget/mobicomkitui/3.38/mobicomkitui-3.38.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/applozic/communication/uiwidget/mobicomkitui/3.38/mobicomkitui-3.38.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/applozic/communication/uiwidget/mobicomkitui/3.38/mobicomkitui-3.38.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/applozic/communication/uiwidget/mobicomkitui/3.38/mobicomkitui-3.38.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/applozic/communication/uiwidget/mobicomkitui/3.38/mobicomkitui-3.38.jar
>        Required by:
>            BevyPhase1:app:unspecified

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: Do you have a `respositories { }` section of your Gradle file?

Comment: It happens because you have to add the jcenter() repo. This library is not in the mavenCentral.

Comment: But if jcenter() is added then Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1, Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0 etc which are present in https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/master/app/build.gradle occurs...I am udating my SDK that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project's build.gradle file, and add jcenter()

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
            classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1'
            //classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
           // classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
            classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Source: 
https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Now it shows six errors like Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1, Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
etc and they are not in my dependencies

Comment: @UrjaPawar can you try with:            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: also use buildToolsVersion as 23.0.2 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

 dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
   compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:3.39'
}
```

Comment: I added repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} in build.gradle(module:app) , didn't work

Comment: it seems to be working for me. can you paste your whole gradle fail log ?

Comment: I have shared a snapshot of same

Comment: it seems to be resolved for me too 3.38 version. are you have some proxy issue or something. can you try to include some other open source gradle lib successfully ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112035/discussion-between-shubhank-and-urja-pawar).